# python: is there a function to unstring an equation read from a file

Tags: python, string

I read an equation from a text file with this shape:

```py
line = "a*x**2+b"
```

I would like to be able to use this equation in a function in this way:

```py
def eval_func(a,x,b):
    z = unstring(line)
    return z
```

The expression of the line can change, but the parameters are fixed.

Is there a way to do that for strings like it is possible to do with `*args` and `**kwargs`?

Thanks for help

Comment: You mean like [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)?

Comment: thank you I never heard about it! YES, it works !! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the IamFr0ssT recommandations I add some highlight:

eval() help to evaluate a string expression:

```
line = "a*x**2+b"
def eval_func(line,a=1,x=1,b=1):
    z = eval(line)
    return z
eval_func(line) => 2
```

it is also interesting to have a look at exec(), because exec can execute informations contained in a text sample. BUT if eval() return something, exec() don't! For example:

```
eval('1+1') return 2
exec('1+1') return nothing

eval('a=1') failed
exec('a=1') is associating the value 1 to variable a
```